# Visual Studio 2012 Installation Error

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2012

I have a weird error installing VS 2012 (Premium or Professional)
The installer in quitting quickly after starting, the log file for the install is actually stopping at

```
[13F4:0568][2013-02-21T16:53:24]: Ux Started
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are there any errors or warnings in the log?

Comment: no, nothing at all, only this as the last line

Comment: Are you on a pre-release version of Windows 8

Comment: No i'm on windows 7

Comment: ask it in the MSDN forum and upload MS the required logs: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/threads

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a pre-release version of Windows 8 then you can't install VS2012

You possibly need to have .NET 4.5 already installed

You possibly need to have the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2005 and 2008 installed

Make sure you are installing the correct 32 or 64bit version for your machine.

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl-BE/vssetup/thread/a7f9f102-a352-42fc-b80d-e6ed437ef9e3)

Comment: I'm on windows 7

Comment: I have both Visual C++ Redistributables, and .Net 4.5 already installed :)

Comment: @Kheu Do you already have blend installed?

Comment: yes I believe so, why?

Comment: ok, but the problem is there's no seperate installer for Blend, I've searched a bit, and the only way to uninstall it from the VS installer in 'Program and Features' (which also has the same problem)

Comment: + why would VS try to install Blend before even fully opening the installer or at least me agreeing on the EULA or something

Comment: @Kheu I don't know - as I said, this was running out of ideas. Maybe skip this idea

Comment: @Kheu - Because VS will install everything it requires to install before it gives you any configuration options with ITS installation.

Answer (score 0):

Just if anyone else is having the same problems, I fixed the error by running the SFC scan command:

```
sfc /scannow
```

in command window (with admin privileges). Apparently I had corrupted file system files.